# Right Filter For After Request Processing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am using the authentication filter to create an instance of an Entity Framework `dbcontext` which is an unmanaged resource. I am going to use it inside the controllers by accessing it through `HttpContext.Current.Items`. (Created a base controller class to make this property available to all controllers).

`dbcontext` needs to be disposed after the controller action is executed. I might wrap each action method call with a using statement but it seems redundant.

Can I use a filter after request is processed to dispose the resource? Which filter would be suitable for this purpose? (The question is for both MVC and Web API)

Or would you advise a totally different architecture for what I am doing?

Answer (score 2):

> Or would you advise a totally different architecture for what I am doing?

I would suggest you a different approach using a Dependency Injection framework to take care of the DbContext lifetime. Configure a DbContext instance in your container to be an instance per HTTP request ensuring that the same instance will be automatically injected in all places where needed within the same HTTP request and automatically disposed at the end of it.

Most modern DI frameworks support per-request instance lifetimes. For example here's [`an article`](http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2013/03/27/managing-entity-framework-dbcontext-lifetime-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx) illustrating how this can be done with Ninject:

```
kernel.Bind<EmployeeContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
```

Now in every single action filter, controller, repository, service or whatever dependency you like takes your DbContext as constructor parameter, the same instance will be injected within the boundaries of the HTTP request which is the desired behavior - db contexts should be as short living as possible and scoped to the lifetime of an HTTP request.

Using this approach you are delegating the management of the DbContext instances to your DI framework and do not need to pollute your controllers with base controllers and other plumbing code.